# Break up 32-bit hex value into 4 bytes [QB64]

Tags: memory, qb64

I would want to ask, how do you break up a 32-bit hex (for example: CEED6644) into 4 bytes (var1 = CE, var2 = ED, var3 = 66, var4 = 44). In QB64 or QBasic. I would use this to store several data bytes into one array address.
Something like this:

```
DIM Array(&HFFFF&) AS _UNSIGNED LONG
Array(&HAA00&) = &HCEED6644&
addr = &HAA00&
SUB PrintChar
SHARED addr

IF var1 = &HAA& THEN PRINT "A"
IF var1 = &HBB& THEN PRINT "B"
IF var1 = &HCC& THEN PRINT "C"
IF var1 = &HDD& THEN PRINT "D"
IF var1 = &HEE& THEN PRINT "E"
IF var1 = &HFF& THEN PRINT "F"
IF var1 = &H00& THEN PRINT "G"
IF var1 = &H11& THEN PRINT "H"
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use integer division (`\`) and bitwise AND (`AND`) to accomplish this.

```
DIM x(0 TO 3) AS _UNSIGNED _BYTE
a& = &HCEED6644&
x(0) = (a& AND &HFF000000&) \ 2^24
x(1) = (a& AND &H00FF0000&) \ 2^16
x(2) = (a& AND &H0000FF00&) \ 2^8
x(3) = a& AND &HFF&
PRINT HEX$(x(0)); HEX$(x(1)); HEX$(x(2)); HEX$(x(3))
```

Note that you could alternatively use a generic `RShift~&` function instead of raw integer division since what you're really doing is shifting bits:

```
x(0) = RShift~&(a& AND &HFF000000&, 18)
...

FUNCTION RShift~& (value AS _UNSIGNED LONG, shiftCount AS _UNSIGNED BYTE)
    ' Raise illegal function call if the shift count is greater than the width of the type.
    ' If shiftCount is not _UNSIGNED, then you must also check that it isn't less than 0.
    IF shiftCount > 32 THEN ERROR 5
    RShift~& = value / 2^shiftCount
END FUNCTION
```

Building upon that, you might create another function:

```
FUNCTION ByteAt~%% (value AS _UNSIGNED LONG, position AS _UNSIGNED BYTE)
    'position must be in the range [0, 3].
    IF (position AND 3) <> position THEN ERROR 5
    ByteAt~%% = RShift~&(value AND LShift~&(&HFF&, 8*position), 8*position)
END FUNCTION
```

Note that an `LShift~&` function was used that shifts bits to the left (multiplication by a power of 2). A potentially better alternative would be to perform the right-shift first and just mask the lower 8 bits, eliminating the need for `LShift~&`:

```
FUNCTION ByteAt~%% (value AS _UNSIGNED LONG, position AS _UNSIGNED BYTE)
    'position must be in the range [0, 3].
    IF (position AND 3) <> position THEN ERROR 5
    ByteAt~%% = RShift~&(value, 8*position) AND 255
END FUNCTION
```

Incidentally, another QB-like implementation known as FreeBASIC has an actual `SHR` operator, used like `MOD` or `AND`, to perform a shift operation directly instead of using division, which is potentially faster.

You could also use QB64's `DECLARE LIBRARY` facility to create functions in C++ that will perform the shift operations:

```
/*
 * Place in a separate "shift.h" file or something.
 */
unsigned int LShift (unsigned int n, unsigned char count)
{
    return n << count;
}

unsigned int RShift (unsigned int n, unsigned char count)
{
    return n >> count;
}
```

Here's the full corresponding QB64 code:

```
DECLARE LIBRARY "shift"
    FUNCTION LShift~& (value AS _UNSIGNED LONG, shiftCount AS _UNSIGNED _BYTE)
    FUNCTION RShift~& (value AS _UNSIGNED LONG, shiftCount AS _UNSIGNED _BYTE)
END DECLARE

x(0) = ByteAt~%%(a&, 0)
x(1) = ByteAt~%%(a&, 1)
x(2) = ByteAt~%%(a&, 2)
x(3) = ByteAt~%%(a&, 3)
END

FUNCTION ByteAt~%% (value AS _UNSIGNED LONG, position AS _UNSIGNED BYTE)
    'position must be in the range [0, 3].
    IF (position AND 3) <> position THEN ERROR 5
    ByteAt~%% = RShift~&(value, 8*position) AND 255
END FUNCTION
```

If QB64 had a documented API, it might be possible to raise a QB64 error from the C++ code when the shift count is too high, rather than relying on the behavior of C++ to essentially ignore shift counts that are too high. Unfortunately, this isn't the case, and it might actually cause more problems than it's worth.

Comment: Oh, Thank you! That was probably the most detailed answer I've seen in my life!

Answer (score 0):

This snip gets the byte pairs of a hexidecimal value:

```
DIM Value AS _UNSIGNED LONG
Value = &HCEED6644&
S$ = RIGHT$("00000000" + HEX$(Value), 8)
PRINT "Byte#1: "; MID$(S$, 1, 2)
PRINT "Byte#2: "; MID$(S$, 3, 2)
PRINT "Byte#3: "; MID$(S$, 5, 2)
PRINT "Byte#4: "; MID$(S$, 7, 2)
```